# PSQL: "Must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" error when using JOIN function

Tags: sql, psql

I am attempting to join a table but I am getting an error.

I need to provide a subquery, but don't know where. This is what I have tried.

```
select q.id, q."createdAt", count(qq.id), "AccountId", "ProgramId" 
from "Quizzes" q 
join "QuizQuestions" qq on "QuizId" = q.id 
join "Accounts" a on a.id = "AccountId" 
where "ProductId" = 'abfb4db4-8605-46dd-a23d-ae52a28c1940' 
       and "selectedOptionIndex" is not null 
       and q."createdAt" >= '1-7-19' 
group by q.id;
```

Results in : `ERROR:  column "a.ProgramId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-aggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select q.id, q."createdAt", count(qq.id), "AccountId", "ProgramId"
from "Quizzes" q join
     "QuizQuestions" qq
     on qq."QuizId" = q.id join
     "Accounts" a
     on a.id = "AccountId"
where "ProductId" = 'abfb4db4-8605-46dd-a23d-ae52a28c1940' and
      "selectedOptionIndex" is not null and
       q."createdAt" >= '2017-01-17'
group by q.id, q."createdAt", "AccountId", "ProgramId";
```

I changed the date format to a standard date format.  You should also alias all the column references with their table aliases.  And, all the double quotes are just confusing.  Do you really need them?

Comment: Thank you. I inherited this. Big help.